# Fail to copy file/folder in external drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am using Windows 10 Pro. Recently one of my flash drives failed to copy files, so I followed an instruction to block external drive copy and unblock it but after that, it won't copy any file/folder to external drives.

Every time I try to copy/paste a file/folder I am getting a "Destination Folder Access Denied" prompt.

[image: Error 1]

When I "Continue" it prompts a failure promptly.
[image: Error 2]

Comment: Not being able to write files to a flash drive is a common sign the drive is failing. But in your case, you should also check the file permissions first. Please tell us the precise steps you followed to "block... and unblock" access.

Answer (score 0):

If it writes to other drives, and fails just on that one, then 99% sure it's a failing drive (although some drives have a physical read/write switch on them, check it doesn't first).

If it is not writing to any drive, you have created a permissions problem, and you need to step back through the steps you took, and see which you did wrong.

Comment: Ya, it does write to drive and folders within the device but just with external drive the issue persists. I have reverted the steps that I did in regedit but nothing helps.

Comment: Hi Hasan, I am sorry from your comment I still can't tell if ALL external drives don't work, or just this one. I can see you have an issue with external devices, and not the local drive in the PC, but I am trying to establish if it is a problem with one external device or all. That will narrow the cause. You might be trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.